# GDataXML iOS getting value

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, gdataxml

I would like to get the "0" value in this XML using GDataXML in iOS :

```
            <typeadresse type="java.lang.Integer">0</typeadresse>
```

I do

`if ([unePosition elementsForName:@"idagencedepart"])
        {
            NSLog(@"position : %@",[unePosition elementsForName:@"idagencedepart"]);
        }`

But it prints :

`position : (
    "GDataXMLElement 0x11f73fb0: {type:1 name:idagencedepart xml:\"<idagencedepart type=\"java.lang.Integer\">4</idagencedepart>\"}"
)`

How do I get the "4" value ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information in your example do not match. Anyway, I assume typeadresse = idagencepedart. You actually almost had the answer. To get the value you need:

```
 GDataXMLElement *element = [[unePosition elementsForName:@"idagencepedart"] objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *value = [element stringValue];
```